# AgoraChat SDK in Unity Issue, error CS0103: The name 'agoraChatClient' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, agora.io

I am trying to implement AgoraChat feature inside my Unity Project and I have followed their documentation.

I have followed the documentation as provided by Agora in their AgoraChat SDK Quickstart [text](https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=unity) but I am receiving a missing AgoraChatClient reference. I'm not sure how to solve this error.
Here is my full script for the NewBehaviourScript as mentioned.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using AgoraChat;
using AgoraChat.MessageBody;


public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour, IChatManagerDelegate, IConnectionDelegate
{
    private TMP_Text messageList;
    private string userId = ""; //Had filled out this as well as token and appkey
    private string token = ""; 
    private string appKey = "";
    private bool isJoined = false;

    public void OnMessagesReceived(List<Message> messages)
    {
        foreach (Message msg in messages) 
        {
            if (msg.Body.Type == MessageBodyType.TXT)
            {
                TextBody txtBody = msg.Body as TextBody;
                string Msg = msg.From + ":" + txtBody.Text;
                displayMessage(Msg, false);
            }
        }
    }
    public void OnCmdMessagesReceived(List<Message> messages)
    {
        // This callback is triggered only by the reception of a command message that is usually invisible to users.
    }
    public void OnMessagesRead(List<Message> messages)
    {
        // Occurs when a read receipt is received for a message.
    }
    public void OnMessagesDelivered(List<Message> messages)
    {
        // Occurs when a delivery receipt is received.
    }
    public void OnMessagesRecalled(List<Message> messages)
    {
        // Occurs when a received message is recalled.
    }
    public void OnReadAckForGroupMessageUpdated()
    {
        // Occurs when the read status updates of a group message is received.
    }
    public void OnGroupMessageRead(List<GroupReadAck> list)
    {
        // Occurs when a read receipt is received for a group message.
    }
    public void OnConversationsUpdate()
    {
        // Occurs when the number of conversations changes.
    }
    public void OnConversationRead(string from, string to)
    {
        // Occurs when the read receipt is received for a conversation.
    }
    public void MessageReactionDidChange(List<MessageReactionChange> list)
    {
        // Occurs when the reactions change.
    }
    public void OnConnected()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected");
    }   
    public void OnTokenExpired()
    {
        // Occurs when the token has expired.
    }   
    public void OnTokenWillExpire()
    {
        // Occurs when the token is about to expire.
    }
    public void OnAuthFailed()
    {
        // Occurs when the user is forced to log out of the current account due to an authentication failure.
    }
    public void OnKickedByOtherDevice()
    {
        // Occurs when the user is forced to log out of the current account on the current device due to login to another device.
    }
    public void OnLoginTooManyDevice()
    {
        // Occurs when the user is forced to log out of the current account because he or she reached the maximum number of devices that the user can log in to with the current account.
    }
    public void OnChangedIMPwd()
    {
        // Occurs when the user is forced to log out of the current account because the login password has changed.
    }
    public void OnForbidByServer()
    {
        // Occurs when the current user account is banned.
    }
    public void OnRemovedFromServer()
    {
        // Occurs when the current user account is removed from the server.
    }
    public void OnLoggedOtherDevice()
    {
        // Occurs when the user logs in to another device with the current account.
    }
    public void OnDisconnected()
    {
        Debug.Log("Disconnected");
    }



    public void joinLeave()
    {
        if (isJoined)
        {
            agoraChatClient.Logout(true, callback: new CallBack(
            onSuccess: () =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Logout succeed");
                isJoined = false;
                GameObject.Find("joinBtn").GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "Join";
            },
            onError: (code, desc) =>
            {
                Debug.Log($"Logout failed, code: {code}, desc: {desc}");
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            agoraChatClient.LoginWithAgoraToken(userId, token, callback: new CallBack(
            onSuccess: () =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Login succeed");
                isJoined = true;
                GameObject.Find("joinBtn").GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "Leave";
            },
            onError: (code, desc) =>
            {
                Debug.Log($"Login failed, code: {code}, desc: {desc}");
            }));
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage()
    {
        string recipient = GameObject.Find("userName").GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text;
        string Msg = GameObject.Find("message").GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text;
        if (Msg == "" || recipient == "")
        {
            Debug.Log("You did not type your message");
            return;
        }
        Message msg = Message.CreateTextSendMessage(recipient, Msg);
        displayMessage(Msg, true);
        agoraChatClient.ChatManager.SendMessage(ref msg, new CallBack(
            onSuccess: () =>
            {
                Debug.Log($"Send message succeed");
                GameObject.Find("message").GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text = "";
            },
            onError: (code, desc) =>
            {
                Debug.Log($"Send message failed, code: {code}, desc: {desc}");
            }));
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject.Find("userName/Text Area/Placeholder").GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = "Enter recipient name";
        GameObject.Find("message/Text Area/Placeholder").GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = "Message";
        messageList = GameObject.Find("scrollView/Viewport/Content").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        messageList.fontSize = 14;
        messageList.text = "";
        GameObject button = GameObject.Find("joinBtn");
        button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(joinLeave);
        button = GameObject.Find("sendBtn");
        button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(sendMessage);
        setupChatSDK();
    }

    void setupChatSDK()
    {
        if (appKey == "")
        {
            Debug.Log("You should set your appKey first!");
            return;
        }
        // Initialize the Agora Chat SDK
        Options options = new Options(appKey);
        options.UsingHttpsOnly = true;
        options.DebugMode = true;
        agoraChatClient = SDKClient.Instance;
        agoraChatClient.InitWithOptions(options);
        agoraChatClient.ChatManager.AddChatManagerDelegate(this);

    }

    public void displayMessage(string messageText, bool isSentMessage)
    {
        if (isSentMessage)
        {
            messageList.text += "<align=\"right\"><color=black><mark=#dcf8c655 padding=\"10, 10, 0, 0\">" + messageText + "</color></mark>\n";
        }
        else
        {
            messageList.text += "<align=\"left\"><color=black><mark=#ffffff55 padding=\"10, 10, 0, 0\">" + messageText + "</color></mark>\n";
        }
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        agoraChatClient.ChatManager.RemoveChatManagerDelegate(this);
        agoraChatClient.Logout(true, callback: new CallBack(
            onSuccess: () => 
            {
                Debug.Log("Logout succeed");
            },
            onError: (code, desc) => 
            {
                Debug.Log($"Logout failed, code: {code}, desc: {desc}");
            }));
    }

}
```

Comment: the error is correct - you have not defined it

Comment: wait but there isn't any separate declaration in the documentation mentioned. Could you please clarify with respect to the link?

Comment: It seems the "SDKClient agoraChatClient; " declaration is missing there.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure what would have been the correct declaration type but it worked. I appreciate for your time and effort. @CarlsonYuan